# Store Roles and Authorizations in a static variable for speed optimization in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, roles, static-variables

I have been debating myself with the idea of storing the application roles and authorizations in a static variable that could be used by all sessions.

I know there is the possibility of concurrency issues. But this information is very rarely ever changed, only by administrators, and most of the time require an application restart with new features anyway. So its almost always read-only for users.

I was thinking of doing this because it can speed things up by not having to constantly go into the database to get the same information every time a user wants to access a method.

Also, it would not store any user specific information, just the information of the roles and specific method authorizations themselves.

What do you guys think? Would it be ok to use static variables in this scenario? Is there a better way to do it? Am I missing some critical security/logical flaw?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use claims for this? Once you add a claim value it will available during all session life time

Comment: I thought about using Claims, but they are stored on the client side and I don't want the client to have any form of access to this information